# Power Automate updating expression automatically to wrong value?

Tags: json, power-automate

Not sure if any one else has noticed this behavior in Power Automate. So I would click on a dynamic content expression, and see something I needed to fix like body('parse json')?['variable_1']?[variabl_2] but [variable_2] is not inside ['variable_1']. Then after deleting the ?['variable_1'] value and clicking update, then clicking the expression again it would pull up the old value, body('parse json')?['variable_1']?[variabl_2]. I had to delete the whole object body('parse json')?['variable_1']?[variabl_2] then go to Dynamic content and re-add it then update and then it worked. I believe it has to do with changing my Json Schema around or possibly about how the cache is done. Like if the dynamic content was created with the old schema where [variable_2] was in [variable_1] then it would keep correcting to the old version because you can't get [variable_2] without having ?[variable_1] in place. I'll try to recreate this phenomenon again but was curious if any of you had seen it? I think it means you need to delete variables related to old json schema or it may autocorrect based on old json schema it is pointing to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's kind of pointless.  If he's overcome it, so be it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about coding as much as it is an inquiry into the experience of people using Power Automate.